# How to unparse html code?

Tags: html, jsp

In my database there is this data : `&euro;` . When I retrieve it and display it inside a html select element then the data is parsed and transformed to be the symbol € :

```
<select  class="form-control" name="monnai_code" >
    <option value="" >${global_select_option}</option>
    <c:forEach var="monnaie" items="${monnaieList}" >
        <option value="${monnaie.code}" ${selectedMonnaie == monnaie.code ? 'selected' : ''}>${monnaie.code} - ${monnaie.lib}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

So how to unparse it ?

Comment: Where, in html? html will do that automatically. unless your script htmlencodes strings, then you end up with `&ampeuro;`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jsp]? You are talking about dealing with the results of the *browser* parsing the HTML, so any programming that would be involved would have to use [tag:javascript]. JSP runs on the server, which has no access to the internals of the browser.

Comment: You might want to rephrase and add detail to your question so that we can understand exactly what you are doing and what you hope to achieve.